# find path in directed graph according to word

Tags: graphs

I have a tricky problem, look:
$n, \le 100, m\le 1000 $ where $m$ is number of edges and $n$ is number of nodes.
On every directed edge there is word $w$ such that $|w| \le 1000$.  There is given one word $s$ ($|s|\le 100000$). Our task is asnwer to question:
Is there transition in this graph such that we build this word $s$ ?

Look at example: answer: YES
[image]

Could you help me ?

Comment: And what is *your* question? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Also, what *is* the task here? Develop an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain the basics of the solution without details.

Define $T[u,i]$ as "Is it possible to make $s[1..i]$ when I am at vertex $u$?".

Obviously for all $u$, $T[u, 0] = true$.

If there is an edge from vertex $u$ to vertex $v$ and the word on the edge matches with $s[i+1..j]$ and $T[u, i] = true$, we can infer that $T[v, j]$ is also $true$.

So you can repeatedly do this process and calculate $T$ for all $u$ and $i$. If $T[x, |s|] = true$ for some $x$, we can make the word!